# How can i share a picture from my google drive for a import to Docs per script

Tags: google-drive-api, share, google-docs, google-docs-api

i take this simply script the manage my letters:

```
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader();
  body.clear();

  var cells = [
  ['', ''],
  ];

  var myT = body.appendTable(cells);

  var picture = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google.a51985becaa6.png");
  myT.getCell(0, 0).appendImage(picture.getBlob());

  myT.getCell(0, 1).clear()
  var txt = myT.getCell(0, 1).editAsText();
  txt.setText("\nThats me");

  txt.setFontFamily("Arial");
  txt.setFontSize(0, txt.getText().length-1, 22);
```

In GoogleDirve i have a picture which i want to use in my letter-headline. When i will share the picture i get a link like this: "https://........0B9nuxx16xEgdT593SSSkUVZJw4c/view?usp=sharing". --> But this link is not working in the script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following sample script?

The image blob can be retrieved using `DriveApp.getFileById(fileID)`. From your question, it seems that the ID of the shared image is "0b9nuxx16xegdt593ssskuvzjw4c". If this is wrong ID, please modify it in the sample script.

#### Sample Script :

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
body.clear();

var cells = [
['', ''],
];

var myT = body.appendTable(cells);

var picture = DriveApp.getFileById("0b9nuxx16xegdt593ssskuvzjw4c");
myT.getCell(0, 0).appendImage(picture.getBlob());

myT.getCell(0, 1).clear()
var txt = myT.getCell(0, 1).editAsText();
txt.setText("\nThats me");

txt.setFontFamily("Arial");
txt.setFontSize(0, txt.getText().length-1, 22);
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @J. Doe Welcome. Thank you, too.